# Contador aumenta inesperadamente dentro de un bucle

Tags: c++, loops

Estoy intentando hacer un pequeño program en C++ que pida al usuario un rango de valores `(xmin, xmax) , (ymin, ymax)`.

El programa `aleatoriamente` escogerá dos valores entre `(xmin, xmax) y (ymin, ymax)` respectivamente y los multiplicará.

El programa pedirá en otro paso el número que crea el usuario que es el resultado de la multiplicación de ambos valores y en caso de fallar `aumentará el contador de intentos en 1`. Y pedirá al usuario si quiere continuar probando.

El código que tengo se muestra a continuación:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>

/* run this program using the console pauser or add your own getch, system("pause") or input loop */

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int a, b; 
    int opc;
    int intentos = 0;
    int max1,max2,min1,min2;
    int num1,num2,result,propuesta;
    char repeat;
    int defined;

    do{
        printf("--------------------------------\n");
        printf("1. Indicar rango inicial y final\n");
        printf("2. Generar multiplicacion\n");
        printf("3. Salir del progrma\n");
        printf("--------------------------------\n");
        scanf("%d",&opc);

        switch(opc) {
            case 1:  //system("cls");
                printf("Dime el minimo del multiplicando 1: \n");
                scanf("%d",&min1);
                printf("Dime el maximo del multiplicando 1: \n");
                scanf("%d",&max1);
                printf("Dime el minimo del multiplicando 2: \n");
                scanf("%d",&min2);
                printf("Dime el maximo del multiplicando 2: \n");
                scanf("%d",&max2);
                printf("\n Has actualizado los rangos \n");
                srand((unsigned) time(NULL)); //multiplicando 1 
                num1 = min1 + rand()%(max1-min1);  
                srand((unsigned) time (NULL)); //multiplicando 2
                num2 = min2 + rand ()%(max2-min2); 
                result = num1*num2; // poner en variables
                intentos = 0; //contador
                defined = 1; // rangos definidos
                break;
            case 2:
                if (defined == 0){ // rangos definidos?
                    printf("No has definido los rangos, vuelve a la opcion 1 del menu principal \n");
                    break;
                }
                do {
                    printf("Introduce el resultado que crees que pueda tener la operacion: \n");
                    scanf("%d", &propuesta);
                    //intentos++;
                    printf("intentos: " + intentos);
                    if(propuesta == result){
                        printf("Has acertado! \n");
                        printf("Para ello has necesitado %d intentos \n", &intentos);
                        //break;
                    } else {
                        printf("Has fallado! \n");
                        intentos++;

                        printf("Quieres intentarlo de nuevo? (S/N) \n %d", &intentos);
                        fflush(stdin); 
                        repeat = toupper(getchar());   
                    }
                    break;
                } while (repeat != 'N');
                break;
            }
        } while (opc != 3);
    printf("Adios! Has utilizado %d intentos y no los has conseguido \n", &intentos);

    return 0;
}
```

Al compilarlo y ejecutarlo puedo comprobar como en el primer fallo el contador tiene el valor de `6618692` y aunque siga intentándolo el contador no cambia de valor.

Tengo ciertas sospechas de que el problema puede estar en el bucle, aunque no lo sé ciertamente. Soy nuevo en C++.

**`¿Dónde puede estar el error que causa que el contador tenga ese valor?`**

Aquí les dejo un ejemplo de output:

```
--------------------------------
1. Indicar rango inicial y final
2. Generar multiplicacion
3. Salir del progrma
--------------------------------
1
Dime el minimo del multiplicando 1:
2
Dime el maximo del multiplicando 1:
3
Dime el minimo del multiplicando 2:
2
Dime el maximo del multiplicando 2:
3

 Has actualizado los rangos
--------------------------------
1. Indicar rango inicial y final
2. Generar multiplicacion
3. Salir del progrma
--------------------------------
2
Introduce el resultado que crees que pueda tener la operacion:
2
intentos: Has fallado!
Quieres intentarlo de nuevo? (S/N)
 6618692
```

Comment: ¿Qué es `time` en esta línea, `srand((unsigned) time(NULL)); //multiplicando 1 `?

Comment: Esta parte de código me la dieron para generar números aleatorios.En teoría el ejemplo que nos dieron para generar números aleatorios usaba esas dos líneas. No sé si es necesaria.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Me parece que estas fallando en las salidas por pantalla, prueba cambiando la ultima linea de printf por lo que te dejare, ademas debes cambiar las otras formas de impresion.

```
printf("Adios! Has utilizado %i intentos y no los has conseguido \n", intentos);
```

Al intentarlo una vez  me indico el 1. Espero haberte ayudado.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Muchas gracias!

Answer (score 3):

Como te han indicado, la causa del error es:

```
&intentos
```

Estas pasando **la dirección de la variable** `intentos`, y no **su valor**, que es lo que espera la función `printf( )`.

En `scanf( )` **si** has de utilizar un **puntero**, porque dicha función *necesita una dirección de memória* en la que almacenar el dato.

En otras palabras: `&intentos != intentos`.
Lo primero devuelve un *puntero* que, valga la redundancia, *apunta* a la dirección de memória en la que se encuentra el dato.
Lo segundo devuelve *el dato* en si, *su valor*.